# What there is no resource leak when Scanner variable declared in class data field?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, resource-leak

When I do write this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

//  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static double y;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = someMethod(5);
    }

    private static double someMethod(int nr) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            y = input.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {System.out.println("Type in a double");}
        return y + nr;
    }
}
```

I get "resource leak" error message.

But when I do write this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static double y;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = someMethod(5);
    }

    private static double someMethod(int nr) {
        try {
            y = input.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {System.out.println("Type in a double");}
        return y + nr;
    }
}
```

It just does work. Why is there no resource leak when I define input Scanner on the class data field?

What is the difference between declaring a variable on the data field vs in a method?

Comment: One `System.in` is a global, two the `Scanner` is never eligible for garbage collection. So the resource leaks exactly once, and is cleaned up when the JVM exits. Same as `System.in` and `System.out`

Answer (score 1):

When you have `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` in the method, you're creating a `new Scanner` instance **every time** the method is called, and you only use it once. This creates garbage because now you will have a new Scanner which isn't being used anymore every time you use the method.

If you instantiate the `Scanner` in the class instead, you create it once and **re-use** it, preventing your program from having garbage.